# Read XML file just like python's lxml with C#?

Tags: c#, python, xml, lxml

```
  <Connections>
     <Connection ID = "1" Source="1:0" Sink="4:0"/>
     <Connection ID = "2" Source="2:0" Sink="4:1"/>
     <Connection ID = "3" Source="2:0" Sink="5:0"/>
     <Connection ID = "4" Source="3:0" Sink="5:1"/>
     <Connection ID = "5" Source="4:0" Sink="6:0"/>
     <Connection ID = "6" Source="5:0" Sink="7:0"/>
  </Connections>
```

When I need to get info from the previous XML code, Python's lxml can be used as follows.

```
def getNodeList(self):
    connection = self.doc.find('Connections')
    cons = connection.find('Connection')

    for con in cons.iter():
        con.get("ID") # get attribute
        ...
```

- What C# libraries/function can I use for getting the info like python's lxml? I mean, can I use find()/iter() or similar with C#?
- What C# libraries are similar to python's lxml?

### ADDED

Based on dtb's answer, I could get what I needed.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace HIR {
  class Dummy {

    static void Main(String[] argv) {

      XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test2.xml");

      var connection = doc.Descendants("Connections"); // .First();
      var cons = connection.Elements("Connection");

      foreach (var con in cons)
      {
        var id = (string)con.Attribute("ID");
        Console.WriteLine(id);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I had to remove the 'First()' to avoid compiler error. With mono I could run the following to get the binary.

```
dmcs /r:System.Xml.Linq main.cs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx):

```
void GetNodeList()
{
    var connection = this.doc.Descendants("Connections").First();
    var cons = connection.Elements("Connection");

    foreach (var con in cons)
    {
        var id = (string)con.Attribute("ID");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `XElement`:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

foreach (var connection in xml.Elements("Connection"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(connection.Attribute("ID").Value);
}
```